# matplotlib ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import on raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am getting b/m error when I try to use matplotlib . I tried many commands but could not fix the error i.e

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
pip install matplotlib
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0xc but this version of numpy is 0xa

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/Python RL plot Nework Topology.py", line 3, in

```
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
```

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/mlab.py", line 167, in 
    from matplotlib.path import Path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 17, in

```
from . import _path, rcParams
```

ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

**and second error**

Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)

[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import matplotlib
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 16, in

from . import multiarray
ImportError: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 141, in

from . import cbook, rcsetup
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook/**init**.py", line 33, in

import numpy as np
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/**init**.py", line 142, in

from . import add_newdocs
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in

from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/**init**.py", line 8, in

from .type_check import *
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in

import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/**init**.py", line 26, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)

ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: libf77blas.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please help. how to fix this error 
Thank in advance

Comment: This might mean that the packages `python-numpy` (or whatever) and `python-matplotlib` are inconsistent. Mixing system packages via `apt-get` and packages installed with `pip` might not be the best idea. Have you tried creating a virtualenv and installing both numpy and matplotlib (and everything else) in there with the same version of python (i.e. the version that lives inside the virtualenv)?

Comment: @AndrasDeak yes i did uninstall and installed though venv env, but again same error

Comment: I have the same kind of error: conda virtual env with pyhon3.6: >>> import matplotlib.colorbar
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
...
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/path.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import _path, rcParams
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import But if I import  numpy.core.multiarray manually it works properly